# Let $B\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times m}$, where $n\geq m$, prove that $B^{*}B$ is invertible if and only if $B$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, matrix-rank, fundamental-solution

My proof: forward direction:
$$(B^{*}B)(B^{*}B)^{-1}=I$$
$$B^{*}B(B^{-1})^{*}B^{-1}=I$$
Only possible when $BB^{-1}=I$.
Now, for the backward direction:
the same way.

Comment: $(B^*B)^{-1}$ is not equal to $(B^{-1})^*B^{-1}$ except in very special circumstances.

Comment: What do you mean by $B$ invertible if $n>m$ ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc , its invertible, what's wrong with it?

Comment: @David, I guess you are correct. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Can you give an example of invertible matrix for  $n=2$ and $m=1$ ?

Comment: Oh, Yeah I think it is wrong. it should be a square matrix.

Comment: In general, $B^*B$ is invertible if and only if the columns of $B$ are linearly independent